# Excel to XML - duplicating records on highest level

Tags: xml, excel

I've got some problem with export from Excel to XML. What I've got:

```
 <tree1>
        <Name>Admin</Name>
        <if1>true</if1>
        <if2>true</if2>
        <Component>
            <Name>name1</Name>
            <Roles>
                <Role>
                    <Role>Admin1</Role>
                </Role>
            </Roles>
        </Component>            
    </tree1>
    <tree1>
        <Name>Admin</Name>
        <if1>true</if1>
        <if2>true</if2>
        <Component>
            <Name>name2</Name>
            <Roles>
                <Role>
                    <Role>Admin2</Role>
                </Role>
            </Roles>
        </Component>            
    </tree1>
```

and in excel:

```
Admin true true name1 Admin1
Admin true true name2 Admin2
```

And what I want to have:

```
    <tree1>
        <Name>Admin</Name>
        <if1>true</if1>
        <if2>true</if2>
            <Component>
            <Name>name1</Name>
            <Roles>
                <Role>
                    <Role>Admin1</Role>
                </Role>
            </Roles>
        </Component> 
        <Component>
            <Name>name2</Name>
            <Roles>
                <Role>
                    <Role>Admin2</Role>
                </Role>
            </Roles>
        </Component>            
    </tree1>
```

How I can modify my xml schema, to do this kind of xml file?